# Can comments be created in macro definition by "/##/"?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

Assuming that the IDE defines macro `NDEBUG` in Release build. Is it possible to use the following preprocessor instructions to print debug information in Debug build but not in Release build by using the marco `PRINT`?

```
#ifdef NDEBUG
#define PRINT /##/
#else
#define PRINT printf
#endif
```

Comment: So, when the preprocessor comes across (say) `PRINT("%d", i);`, you would get `/##/("%d", i);`, which doesn't make sense. Or did your mean `#define PRINT /**/`?

Comment: @AdrianMole: `##` is a macro-replacement pasting operator. They want `PRINT` to produce `//`. They cannot write `#define PRINT //` because the `//` would be taken as a comment during the macro definition, so they want to defer it to macro replacement, hence attempting to construct it via `#define PRINT /##/`. The desired result would be that `PRINT("%d", i);` becomes `//("%d", i);` and is then removed as a comment.

Comment: Even if this worked, you would have to be wary of somebody using additional code on the same line as a `PRINT` invocation, like `if (foo) { PRINT("Calling bar"); bar(); }`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil using `/##/` in macro definition will emit an error during preprocessing process: `pasting "/" and "/" does not give a valid preprocessing token`

Comment: @stanchcorder6: It might or might not give an error. Per my answer, C 2018 6.10.3.3 3 says the behavior is undefined. This means the standard imposes no requirements on an implementation, not even a requirement that an error be issued. And you should note my comment was written with the subjunctive mood.

Comment: you can do that with the proper definition of ```#if defined NDEBUG
    #define PRINT(...)
#else
    #define PRINT(...) printf(__VA_ARGS__)
#endif```

Answer (score 7):

No, because replacement of comments with spaces occurs before macro replacement in C’s translation phases.

C 2018 5.1.1.2 1 specifies the precedence of syntax rules in translation. Phase 3 is:

> The source file is decomposed into preprocessing tokens and sequences of white-space characters (including comments). A source file shall not end in a partial preprocessing token or in a partial comment. Each comment is replaced by one space character…

Phase 4 is:

> Preprocessing directives are executed, macro invocations are expanded…

Interestingly, earlier phases can be invoked by later phases, but this only occurs for processing `#include` directives; the specification for phase 4 continues:

> … A #include preprocessing directive causes the named header or source file to be processed from phase 1 through phase 4, recursively…

Further, pasting `/` with `/` to produce `//` has undefined behavior, because `//` is not a preprocessing token and C 2018 6.10.3 3 says, of pasting with the `##` operator:

> … If the result is not a valid preprocessing token, the behavior is undefined…

(Preprocessing tokens are specified in C 2018 6.4 1, and the relevant category there would be *punctuator*, which includes characters and character combinations such as `[`, `]`, `+`, `++`, `/`, `+=`, `/=`, `>>=`, and so on but does not include `//`.)

A typical means of accomplishing the goal of printing in a debug build but not a non-debug build is to define a function-like macro that is replaced by nothing in non-debug builds:

```
#if defined NDEBUG
    #define PRINT(...)
#else
    #define PRINT(...) printf(__VA_ARGS__)
#endif
```